# How can I update some array entries to have multiple values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array as such:

```
   arr = {
      name: 1,
      address: 1,
      phone: 2,
      email: 5,
   };
```

I want to be able to add further information to this array, eg:

```js
       arr = {
          name: 1 true,
          address: 1 false,
          phone: 2 true,
          email: 5 true,
       };
```

I've tried a few different things like:

```
arr.email[2] = true;
```

With no results (or errors).

Is there a way to do this? Or a better way of handling this issue?

Comment: The "code" for what you want is not valid Javascript.

Comment: arr.email = "5 true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you're going for here since you mention wanting an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (`[]`) but what you've shown in your question is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) (`{}`), but if I'm reading right you can accomplish this with an object where each key holds an array of values. That would look like:

```js
const obj = {
  name: [1],
  address: [1],
  phone: [2],
  email: [5],
};

obj.email.push(true);
obj.email.push("whatever");

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.email[1])
console.log(obj.email[2])
```

So `obj` is an object, but `name`, `address`, `phone`, and `email` are all arrays which you can extend as needed with [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 0):

Original data structure doesn't allow you to add data the way you want. So you  have to create the object with needed data structure at first. After this the original data should be moved to the new object and only after this you can add some new data.

```
     newObj.name.push(origObj.name,true,"something1","something2");
     newObj.address.push(origObj.address,false);
     newObj.phone.push(origObj.phone,true);
     newObj.email.push(origObj.email,true);
```

output

```
{
"name":[1,true,"something1","something2"],
"address":[1,false],
"phone":[2,true],
"email":[5,true]
}
```

original object

```
    var origObj = {
        name: 1,
        address: 1,
        phone: 2,
        email: 5
    };
```

new object

```
    var newObj = {
        name: [],
        address: [],
        phone:[],
        email: []
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to assign a variable to your array and call a function...that way, each element could be classified (boolean, string, integer, etc.) For example,

```
const fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear'];
console.log(fruit);
```